# How do you switch characters in battle in the PS3 version of Tales of Symphonia?

Tags: tales-of-symphonia-hd

In the GameCube version, you could use Z to cycle through the characters in the battle menu.

Maybe I'm missing something obvious, but I don't see any way to switch characters in battle in the PS3 version. Is there a way?

Comment: You'd think there'd be a manual of some kind with the North American standard edition or hopefully with the digital download.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bring up the menu in the middle of the fight and press the start button. It will cycle them through at the bottom.